# C fscanf formatting

Tags: c, scanf

I'm quite new to C and I'm having a bit of trouble with these pieces of code:

```
char word[STRING_LEN];

while(num_words < ARRAY_SIZE && 1 == fscanf(infile, "%79s", &word))
```

When I try to compile, I get the warning:

```
format '%s' expects argument of type char *, but argument 3 has type
char (*)[80].
```

Now this is remedied by using `&word[0]`. Now, shouldn't these both point to
the address at the start of the array? What am I missing here.

Cheers!

Comment: `fscanf(infile, "%79s", word))`

`&word[0]` == `word`

Comment: I suggest `while((num_words < ARRAY_SIZE) && (1 == fscanf(infile, "%79s", &word)))`.  It looks better and could prevent operator precedence logic errors.

Comment: @DavidPullar `fscanf` expects a pointer for the third argument (in this case) and `&word` would essentially be a pointer to pointer to `char`, no?

Comment: An array is a pointer structure, unlike a primitive, therefore does not require `&`

Comment: `&word[0]` and `&word` indicate the same address, but they have different types. A *pointer value* consists of both an address and a type. Pointers of different type may be represented differently in memory, even though they both store the same address.

Comment: [This page](http://www.torek.net/torek/c/pa.html) has a diagram of pointers holding the same address but pointing to different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `%s` format in `fscanf`, it is expected that the argument is a `char*` that can hold the characters being read from the stream. That explains the warning message.

In your case, `&word` has the same numerical value as `&word[0]`. However, that is not true all the time. For example, if you have:

```
char* word = malloc(20);
```

then, the numerical value`&word` is not equal to  that of`&word[0]`. The compiler is not taking the responsibility for dealing with such distinctions. It is simply expecting a `char*` as the argument.

Comment: This is a partial answer.  The type of `&word` is `char (*)[80]` (pointer to an array of 80 characters) and not `char *`, which is why GCC (or Clang) complains about a type mismatch.  When `word` is an array (either file scope or function scope but not a function parameter), then the `void *` values of `word`, `&word[0]` and `&word` are the same, but there are two different types involved.

Comment: `&word` is not the same as `&word[0]`. To see this, try `&word == &word[0]`. You will get a compilation error.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and MattMcNabb, that was a hastily formulated answer, which is updated now.